# C4067 Visual Studio Warning

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, include, warnings

I'm using VS2012 Ultimate and I get a warning when I get this warning (c4067) when I try to include a local header file where I define some constants.

This is how I included the header:

```
#include "constants.h";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidentally put a semicolon after the directive, this was causing the error